# Detect iOS Mobile Device with JavaScript than auto play audio

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, mobile-safari, detect

I would like to Detect iOS Mobile Device or Mobile safari with JavaScript than auto play audio with JavaScript. I have tried versions of this code but its just not playing, any thought on why this is not playing. Thank you

```
function untitledFunction3 (hypeDocument element, event) {

if( isMobile.iOS() );
var audio = new Audio("http://polyflor.squarespace.com/storage/vo/low-res-mp3/PolyFlor_1_intro_timed_sized.mp3");
audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Audio html5 API is not supported in mobile webkit yet.

http://caniuse.com/audio-api

Try using something like soundplayer2, it works in mobile safari, is fairly lightweight, and has fallbacks.

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/